# Is there a way to configure the fields that get "focus" when a record is opened up for editing in Quickbase?

Tags: user-interface, intuit-partner-platform

This is [Quickbase](http://quickbase.intuit.com/).

When I open one of my forms to edit a record, the drop down at the top has "focus".  That means, it's highlighted just as if the user clicked on it.  In a second form I created, nothing seems to have focus when I open up a record to edit.

Is this focus something that can be configured?  I'd rather nothing had focus when the record is opened up for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually called up Intuit support, and it turns out every form should come up with the first field in focus.